# Virtual reality on Windows 10?

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, functionality, lumia-950

So, question is quite simple: I just received e-mail offer from one of e-shops I subscribed to and they are offering a bundle of Lumia 950/ Lumia 950 XL together with an apparatus which allows using phone as VR device.

For better idea, here is screenshot from czech offer:
[image]

Am I actually going to be able to use such apparatus on Windows 10? Is there any VR related app or mention that such phone should be VR ready?

Answer (score 4):

The [Homido VR FAQ](http://www.homido.com/en/how-to-use/faq) ignores Windows Phone completely

> Homido can be used with Android smartphones and iPhones.....You will
>   find the list of the 300+ apps compatible with Homido on our catalog
>   app Homido Center...for Android and iPhone.

but if you go to the Homido VR [compatibility page](http://www.homido.com/en/how-to-use/compatibility), it lists Windows Phone as simply "compatible" (compared to "optimum" with Android and iOS), as well as this note:

> *There are few VR apps available on Windows phone for the time being. But it is possible to watch 3D videos available on Youtube ("3D side
>   by side")

Homido VR also does not have a Windows Phone app, but it does for iOS and Android. The web VR app search on the website lists Android, iOS and Web only. So I'm not sure which apps are available for Windows 10 mobile at all.

Worst case scenario is you only watch 3D Youtube videos on a 70 Euro peripheral...

Answer (score 3):

Lumia 950 can be used as VR gear along with other needed hardwares. A [video](https://youtu.be/UZP96QMvPFo) from Microsoft's YouTube channel shows using VR on Lumia 950.

Lumiaconversationsuk mentions VR in Lumia 950 in this [article](http://lumiaconversationsuk.microsoft.com/2015/11/12/microsoft-lumia-950-showcased-with-virtual-reality-gear-for-virgin-atlantic/),

> Microsoft has been working with Virgin Atlantic to create ‘Ida’, an
>   Immersive Digital Adventure built as a Windows 10 universal app,
>   featuring specially created content that takes the viewer through a
>   virtual Upper Class journey.

It further states,

> The star of the show, amongst some
>   pretty amazing tech, for us has to the use of the brand new Microsoft
>   Lumia 950, the 5.2-inch Windows 10 Mobile device, which is used with
>   virtual reality gear in the video.

**To answer your question**,

> Am I actually going to be able to use such apparatus on Windows 10?

Yes, you can.

> Is there any VR related app or mention that such phone should be VR ready?

Although I find the IDA app in the video to be amazing, I personally don't think there are many VR apps for day to day use till now. But the app situation may change once HoloLens hits the market. In addition as [Tyress](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/18305/tyress) says in [his answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12803/18061) you can play YouTube videos in 3D. But Windows 10 and Lumia 950 are ready to be used in Virtual Reality.

**References** :

1. [Video showing use of Lumia 950 as a VR gadget - YouTube](https://youtu.be/UZP96QMvPFo)
2. [Microsoft Lumia 950 showcased with Virtual Reality gear for Virgin Atlantic - Lumiaconversationsuk](http://lumiaconversationsuk.microsoft.com/2015/11/12/microsoft-lumia-950-showcased-with-virtual-reality-gear-for-virgin-atlantic/)
3. [Microsoft Lumia 950 showcased with Virtual Reality gear for Virgin Atlantic - Nokiapedia.com](http://www.nokipedia.com/microsoft-lumia-950-showcased-with-virtual-reality-gear-for-virgin-atlantic/?shared=email&msg=fail)
4. [Lumia 950 seen with VR Gear in a new official video - Nokiapoweruser](https://nokiapoweruser.com/lumia-950-seen-with-vr-gear-in-a-new-official-video/)